# unable to read csv into Zebras DataFrame in React

Tags: reactjs, pandas

I have a react project,and in this particular class i am trying to use zebras, a library for working with DataFrame-like JSON. I have a class, Maps, and in it i have some consts, one of which im trying to console log.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./Maps.css";
import csv from "./df3.csv"
import map2 from "./vectors/map2.svg"

const z = require('zebras')

const dataframe = z.readCSV(csv)

class Maps extends Component {

    render() {
      const z = require('zebras')
      const dataframe = z.readCSV(csv)
      console.log(dataframe) // in a local Node environment

        return (

            <div style={{justifyContent: 'left', padding: 30 }}>

                <div><h1 class="area">map 1</h1></div>

                <div class="mapMonitor"style={{}}>
                <div class="mapSuperScreen">
                  <div   class="mapScreenDiv" >
                    <div id="mapSubScreen" class="mapSubScreen">
                    <img class='mappy'src={map2}/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="animap"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>

              </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Maps;
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.readFileSync is not a function
    at Module.<anonymous> (readCSV.js:18)
    at Module.f1 (_curry1.js:16)
    at Maps.render (Maps.js:16)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17097)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17050)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18510)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23028)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22019)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:21992)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21610)
    at react-dom.development.js:11130
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:656)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11076)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11125)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11113)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21053)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:24191)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:24590)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:24656)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.0 (index.js:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:785)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

Im not sure if there is something obvious that I'm missing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something `zebras` like this, Hope this will help you :

```
import React from "react";
import * as z from "zebras"; // import like this

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const data = z.readCSV("../public/sample.csv"); // <-- use it like this
    this.state = data;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.map(obj => (
          <p key={obj.id}>
            {obj.name} {obj.surname}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**WORKING DEMO** :

[image: Edit so-react-zebras]